# Does $\int_{X} (f-g)^2 d\mu<\infty$ implies $g \in \mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let  $f \in \mathcal{L}^2(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$  and $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable.
If $\int_{X} (f-g)^2 d\mu<\infty$ does then $g \in \mathcal{L}^2(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ follow?

Comment: What is $\mathcal L(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$? Is it the space of square integrable functions on $X$ with measure $\mu$?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from the triangle inequality $\|g\|_X \leq \|f\|_X + \|f-g\|_X$.

Comment: does this not presuppose that the integral of g is already defined?

Comment: No, because the Lebesgue integral of a positive measurable function (i.e. $\int |g|^2 \mu$ ) is always well-defined, although perhaps infinite. If you prefer, the triangle inequality says that if $a$ and $b$ are in $X$, then $a-b$ is in $X$.

Comment: Ah ok, yes your norm is defined as $||g||_{X}:=\int g^2 d\mu$. Thank you!